# How to know when the phone connects to a WiFi network

Tags: android, wifi, android-broadcast, android-broadcastreceiver

I've been looking for a way to know when my Android smartphone connects to a WiFi network and IS READY to connect to a certain server to exchange data.
I have already tried setting a broadcast receiver that receives the action "WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION" 
But this intent seems to be fired before the WiFi connection is complete (i.e : The phone does not have an IP address yet, and the phone is still in the middle of the connection process), so when you try to connect to a server you get an error.

Is there a reliable way to know if the phone has connected to a WiFi and ready to connect to a server.

I'm really sorry for not adding the code but I don't have my laptop around because I'm on vacation, but I can't get this out of my mind.

Thank you.

Edit :

I also tried every other action that can be used like "wifi_state_change" and several others, but no improvement unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using BrodcastReciever

**Permissions in manifetst**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

**AndroidManifest**

```
<receiver android:name="com.AEDesign.communication.WifiReceiver" >
   <intent-filter android:priority="100">
      <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE" />
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

**BroadcastReceiver class**

```
 public class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

       @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

         // NetworkInfo info = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
//for wifi
    NetworkInfo info = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_WIFI_INFO);
          if(info != null && info.isConnected()) {
            // Do your work. 

            // e.g. To check the Network Name or other info:
            WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
            String ssid = wifiInfo.getSSID();
          }
       }
    }
```

Comment: Well thank you for ypur comment, but wifi state change gets fired before the connection is complete(it actually gets fired several times during the connection process but not when the connection is complete and ready), so when you try to do anything after receiving that action you find out that you are not "completely" connected to the network, and thus you cannot connect to a server on that network.

Comment: you are right, but we can use this condition to make sure. did you try it?

      `if(info != null && info.isConnected()) {`

Comment: as well, try this for wifi 
                            NetworkInfo info = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_WIFI_INFO);

Comment: Actually, what solved it is the connectivity_change action

Comment: You simply set a broadcast receiver for the "ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTIoN".
And when you receive this action you check on "networkInfo.isConnected()" and "networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI".
This way you make sure that you are connected to WiFi network and that the connection is completed.

Comment: Note that this action will be received several times during the connection establishment.